# C# System.ArgumentException: Destination array was not long enough

Tags: c#, thread-safety, serial-port, queue

I have a generic Queue object which is fed from a SerialPort.DataReceived method.

Occasionally I get exception "Destination array was not long enough" when calling the ToArray() method. The code:

```
        byte[] tmpArray;

        try
        {
            tmpArray = queue.ToArray();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
```

For the record: queue.Count never exceeds 500.

Although this is most likely a thread problem, I do not understand the exception. When will a destination array be too short in a queue's ToArray() method?

If this is a thread problem, what is the best practice when it comes to getting data from a SerialPort to a Queue?

BTW: I lock queue before writing. Perhaps I should lock it before ToArray() as well?

Comment: You need a lock everywhere you use the queue. `Enqueue`, `Dequeue`, `ToArray` etc. Consider using thread safe collections

Comment: How did you implement the data received handler?

Comment: lock solved the problem. Rewriting with a thread safe collection (ConcurrentQueue) was too much work. ;-)

Comment: CloudyMarble: SerialPort.DataReceived Event. Inside the event handler check that BytesToRead is greater than null. I read data into a temporary byte array with SerialPort.Read method. Then enqueue. Of course lock the Queue object before writing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I’d like to answer my own question, or at least give a hypothesis to the weird exception message.

This was more like a question to the exception message and why the framework tells me an array is too small even though it’s not up to me to create that array.

As this is most likely a thread related problem, the only way a Queue.ToArray() can throw an exception saying “Destination array was not long enough” is when the queue itself grows in another thread while ToArray tries to copy it..

The ToArray method gives us a new array. Hence that array has to be allocated first and then the data would be copied from the queue to the array. As I said, the SerialPort.DataReceived event handler is responsible for adding elements to the queue. If the SerialPort.DataReceived Event fires right after the array has been allocated, the queue will be larger than the array.

It is probably hard or impossible for the framework to detect this.